# Facebook Real Time Updates For a Page's messages working locally but not on Staging

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, heroku

Ok so some context:

- Our web-app is hosted on Heroku and runs on Ruby-on-Rails. We use the Koala gem to talk to Facebook.
- We also have a staging environment on Heroku.
- I have a local development environment.
- I have a Facebook app setup for the live environment, and two test environments setup - one for the staging environment, and one for the local dev environment.
- The feature that I'm working on allows a user to connect to a FacebookPage and then subscribe to realtime updates to their page's incoming messages.

I have it working on local:

- I'm using ngrok to create an external address, that I'm then registering with Facebook's RealTimeUpdates api to receive all page updates.
- When someone connects their page, the app uses the graph api to get connected to the page to manage it's updates.

This works just fine on my local - I have the app key, secret setup properly and everything loads up fine.

When I deploy to my staging on Heroku, I'm able to do all of the above steps successfully, and see through the Facebook API that staging is in-fact connected, and that the page does list the staging app as a subscribed app.

So, when someone sends a message to the facebook page, only my localhost receives a live-update to my facebook callback, but not my staging. And I have no idea why.

What could I be doing on local that I'm not doing on staging?

Comment: I believe one FB app can only have one real-time updates callback url, so check that the app for production is set up with prod's callback url and the app id used in dev is set up with dev's callback url.

Comment: Yes, we infact did only have one callback per app. Turned out to be a bug in Facebook's RTU. Theyv'e fixed it, but now there are some other issues that we're working out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I'd answer my own question here: it turned out to be a bug in Facebook's RTU.